# Convert my code from perl to shell script

Tags: shell, perl

Please help me out with this. I have code in Perl which is converted in a shell script.

```
#!perl
my @a = (1..7000);
for(@a){
    my $curl=`curl -X GET http://localhost:9333/dir/assign?collection=chetan`;

    print $curl;
    $sub_string1 = substr($curl, 8,15); 
    print $sub_string1;
    $t='curl -X PUT -F file=@/home/user/test.txt http://172.17.0.4:8080/'.$sub_string1;
    print $t;
    my $curl=`$t`;
    #sleep(3)
    # print $curl
}
```

Comment: What have you tried? What problems are you having? Please show us your code.

Answer (score -1):

Completely untested and really a line-by-line translation (no optimisation here, even though some things might be better written):

```
for n in {1..7000}; do
    curl="$(curl -X GET http://localhost:9333/dir/assign?collection=chetan)"
    sub_string1="${curl:8:23}"
    t="curl -X PUT -F file=@/home/user/test.txt http://172.17.0.4:8080/$sub_string1";
    echo $t
    curl="$($t)"
done
```